# Magento 2 Change base image when attribute is selected on catalog page

Tags: magento2, attributes, catalog, image, color-swatches

I want to change the base image depending on the color which is selected. So if i select "Olive Green", all the products with olive color single products must change the base images to the black version.

So, this is the standard catalog page:
[image: So, this is the standard catalog page:]

I change the color with the color swatch:
[image: I change the color with the color swatch]

If i change the color to Olive Green, i see this:
[image: If i want to change the color to Olive Green, i see this:]

But i want to see this:
[image]

All the single products do have their own image. How to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by doing the following:

[image]

AND:
Stores > Configuration > Catalog > Catalog > Storefront > Show Swatches in Product List = YES